# Diffie-Hellman symmetry keys display issue

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, diffie-hellman

I am generating Symmetric-keys by using bouncy castle Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol, but when I display my generated Secret then it gives me the following error

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Key agreement has not been completed yet**

Assume from the below code that keys agreement process has be successfully completed and also from the hashes it confirms that both keys are the similar.

```
    MessageDigest   hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    byte[] aShared = hash.digest(aKeyAgree.generateSecret());
    byte[] bShared = hash.digest(bKeyAgree.generateSecret());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aKeyAgree.generateSecret()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably simply that calling `aKeyAgree.generateSecret()` twice is the issue. The key agreement should be performed just once. If you want to print the result you need to store it in a (temporary) variable instead.

Comment: Yes you are right that was the problem. Thank you very much for your help.